# I have a form which returns select options through ajax call, but when I save the post values are not shown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following form

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Populate City Dropdown Using jQuery Ajax</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.countr").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(".countr option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "countries.php",
            data: { country : selectedCountry } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#response").html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Country:</label>
                <select class="countr">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option value="usa">United States</option>
                    <option value="india">India</option>
                    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                </select>
            </td>
           <td id="response">
                <select class="response">
                    
                   
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

and the following php code

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST["country"])){
    // Capture selected country
    $country = $_POST["country"];
    var_dump($country);

    // Define country and city array
    $countryArr = array(
                    "usa" => array("New York", "Los Angeles", "California"),
                    "india" => array("Mumbai", "New Delhi", "Bangalore"),
                    "uk" => array("London", "Manchester", "Liverpool")
                );

    // Display city dropdown based on country name
    if($country !== 'Select'){
        echo "<label>City:</label>";
        echo "<select>";
        foreach($countryArr[$country] as $value){
            echo "<option>". $value . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    } 
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    var_dump($_POST);
}
?>
```

The ajax returns the data and the select option is filled up.

The issue is when I submit the form, the post data is empty and when I check the source code for options is not there too even the drop down is created.

What am I doing wrong...

Comment: try assigning value in this `echo "<option>". $value . "</option>";`. Do it like this `echo "<option value='". $value . "'>". $value . "</option>";`

Comment: Missing name attribute for select tag ;  Missing option value attribute

Comment: I have done that too, the thing is the source code does not show the form elements.... [screenschot](https://prnt.sc/fumlic)

Comment: did you  have  any error in your console ?

Comment: Nope ... No error

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** Missing `name` attribute for `select` tag

```
echo "<select name='what_ever_you_want'>";
```

**Note :** Without `name attribute` elements are ignored by form . it will not send to server

**2nd :** Missing option `value` attribute

```
echo "<option value='". $value . "'>". $value . "</option>";
```

**3rd :**  **!!IMPORTANT!!** change this if statement `if($country !== 'Select'){  }` to `if($country !=''){ }`

```
if($country != ''){
        echo "<label>City:</label>";
        echo "<select name='city'>";
        foreach($countryArr[$country] as $value){
            echo "<option>". $value . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
```

**Testing 1 :** `done(function(data){ console.log(data); });` put this code and confirm that ajax returning the `data or not`

Comment: I have done that too, the source code does not show the form elements when I right click on the page and show source...

Comment: done(function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }); put this code  and confirm that ajax returning the data or not

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Populate City Dropdown Using jQuery Ajax</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.countr").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(".countr option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "countries.php",
            data: { country : selectedCountry } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#response").html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Country:</label>
                <select class="countr" name="country">
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option value="usa">United States</option>
                    <option value="india">India</option>
                    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
                </select>
            </td>
           <td id="response">
                <select class="response">


                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body> 
</html>


<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $_POST['country']."<br>"; 
    echo $_POST['city'];
}
?>
```

**countries.php**

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST["country"])){
    // Capture selected country
    $country = $_POST["country"];
    //var_dump($country);

    // Define country and city array
    $countryArr = array(
                    "usa" => array("New York", "Los Angeles", "California"),
                    "india" => array("Mumbai", "New Delhi", "Bangalore"),
                    "uk" => array("London", "Manchester", "Liverpool")
                );

    // Display city dropdown based on country name
    //if($country !== 'Select'){
        echo "<label>City:</label>";
        echo "<select name='city'>";
        foreach($countryArr[$country] as $value){
            echo "<option>". $value . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
   // } 
}


?>
```

This Code working for me simple copy and paste it

Look This Output:

[image]

Comment: please specify that what changes you made

Comment: First i should change select tag attribute name  both Countries and City

Comment: Then i would mention post submit method code in same page and i should print country and city same page

Comment: why this line needed ??  if($country !== 'Select'){ }  this is unnecessary

Comment: Yes that line is unnecessary but in between that Select attribute code will need